# Flutter Dynamic Local Notification Icon (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do I have changing Icons similar to how Instagram notifications icons changes by who sends the message.

The way I understand it is notifications can only access image in drawable and mipmap that once the apk is built they can only access that image. What I want to do is allow user to give any image and make it the notifications Icon

Answer (score 0):

Please check _showBigPictureNotificationURL() method from the plugin:

[flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)